# jstl + java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;

Tags: jstl

I am getting a error likewise

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.unExposeVariables(LoopTagSupport.java:587)
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doFinally(LoopTagSupport.java:323)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp.__searchsuccess._jsp__tag3(__searchsuccess.java:359)
    at jsp_servlet._jsp.__searchsuccess._jspService(__searchsuccess.java:191)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
```

I have all this jars included; i guess it is some clashing of jar files. anyone can verify??
[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What version of WebLogic? What version of the JSTL and standard jars? Why do you include servlet-2.3.jar in your webapp? What's the code of the JSP causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `servlet-2.3.jar` & `ESAPI-1.4.4.jar` file from the lib folder & execute program again.

It should work...

Below link will also help you for more details.

[How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Comment: Buddy, i need esapi jar; i will try removing servlet-2.3.jar and check..thanks for the response..

Comment: any luck? is it working?

Comment: NO... :( it is not working out..same issue persists...

Comment: did you removed servlet-2.3.jar file?

Please list the jar files that are there in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: log4j-1.2.14.jar 
spring-asm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar 
spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar 
spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar 
spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar 
spring-expression-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar 
spring-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar 
spring-webmvc-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar 
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar 
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar 
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar 
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar 
standard.jar 
commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar 
ESAPI-1.4.4.jar